# Split and store only part of a file path in the db

Tags: php, sql, split, path, insert

I'm making changes to a php app that's currently storing a full path to a file in the db (via SQL). But, I only want part of the path to be stored in the db. The path is rebuilt later within the application, allowing the path to be changed in just one place if it's ever needed.

Anyway, what is written to the db is something like this:
`Z:/TheStore/apps/myapp/assets/upload/docID/versionNumber\document.doc`

But, what I want to do is remove the `"Z:/TheStore/apps/myapp/assets/upload/"`

And only insert the "docID/versionNumber\document.doc" into the DB.

Anybody have a good idea how to accomplish this?

The first part of the path will always be the same for this individual app, so I think an easy, quick and dirty way would be to somehow just remove the exact string `"Z:/TheStore/apps/myapp/assets/upload/"` from the path before storing it to the db, which would leave the exact part that I want. Or, maybe this is a stupid idea. And you're free to tell me that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE` method in MySQL pretty easily for existing data:

```
UPDATE 
  tablename 
SET 
  columnName = REPLACE(columnName, 'Z:/TheStore/apps/myapp/assets/upload/', '')
```

where `tablename` is the name of table and `columnName` is the column this file path is stored in.

You can do the equivalent in php (or keep track of your docID and versionNumber to make a string relative path would be better) with `str_replace` on the url.

```
$path = str_replace('Z:/TheStore/apps/myapp/assets/upload/','', $path);
```

where `$path` is the full file path.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!